# lint c++ in vscode with google style naming conventions

Tags: c++, lint

I'm looking for a way to lint c++ code to match google style guide [naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming). So for example If I had

```
const int lDaysInAWeek = 7; // Bad - should start with a "k"

std::string tableName;   // Bad - mixed case. Variables should be lowercase with underscores.

void OpenFileorDie(); // Bad - functions should start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word
```

I would like to have squiggles and a QuickFix option when hovering. Is there a way to configure vscode to help me follow conventions?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not an automated way of doing this. A quick test on my machine shows that [even Google's own linter](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint) does not enforce those naming conventions, so I would guess you will not find a premade way to do this.